# reading and storing properties file

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to update a value in property file through the following code

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = Sample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(is);

        p.setProperty("myProperty", "updated");

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myfile.properties");
        p.store(os, "update");
        os.close();
        System.out.print(p.getProperty("myProperty"));
    }
}
```

Output: updated

But the values doesn't seem to get updated. In Fact, I am not getting any error even if the property or the file itself is not present.

Comment: Is this properties file buldled in a JAR?

Comment: no, I have put all of them in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Read properties file.
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}

// Write properties file.
try {
    prop.store(new FileOutputStream("filename.properties"), null);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: I changed my code as above.
And now the problem is that the property file gets updated but it does not get refreshed until the program gets over. So I am not able to retrieve the updated values in the same program later.